# draw curves lines android

Tags: java, android, draw, paint

I drew 4 lines from the center towards the button as I show you in the photo.  I do not know how I can draw curved lines that are in red color in the picture.

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWJLU.png)]

or

[[enter image description here (simpler)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PNRg.png)]

```
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getWidth(), (int) getWindowManager()
            .getDefaultDisplay().getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawingImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int x = metrics.widthPixels;
    int y = metrics.heightPixels;
    Paint paint1 = new Paint () ;
    paint1.setStrokeWidth(10);
    int margin = 100;
    int margin1 = 300;
    int top = 0 + margin;
    int bottom = canvas.getHeight() - margin;
    int left = 0 + margin1;
    int right = canvas.getWidth() - margin1;
    int centerX = x / 2;
    int centerY = y / 2;

    canvas.drawLine(centerX, top, centerX, bottom,paint1);
    canvas.drawLine(left, centerY, right, centerY,paint1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split it in 4 different parts (curves) for easier drawing
Here is my sketch(sorry for quick drawing)

So you need to get 4 points for bezieres and should be something like this
1st move to start (drawing point)

```
path.moveTo(x1, y1);
```

then use next for draw path

```
cubicTo(x2, y2, x3, y3, x4,y4)
```

[image]

and finally

```
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
```

Same procedure make for rest 3 quadrant/parts
hope this will help you to archive your goal

Comment: that is more math calculation, you have button(1) position x,y same for button(3) and intersection for x-y you can get point you need for middle is easy (screen width/2 and screen height/2)

Comment: that is button1 center (so X) and button3 bottom center (so Y)

Comment: I tried with these coordinated, nothing was drawn

 `path1.moveTo(button7.getX(),button7.getY());`
        `path1.cubicTo(button7.getX(),button4.getY(),button4.getX(),button4.getY(), x/2, y/2);`

Comment: I added another image in my question, if I would draw this kind of lines its would be simpler, right?

Comment: post your class (pastebin or similar)